# Rails ajax response and DELETE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs, http-delete

I am having problems with remote links with `delete` method in Rails 4

Whenever I have a link like this

```
<%= link_to "delete this", delete_path, remote: true, method: :delete %>
```

When I click on it, it fire the proper `destroy.js.erb` response, but after that nothing happens on any remote links. On the server things do happen, as I see that stuff get rendered, but on the browser nothing is happening. This makes me need to refresh the page to get other UJS requests to work.

Is this a known issue with ujs and delete?

Is there a way to force all `destroy` actions to be on `post` and not `delete`?

Update:

From my tests, this is happens only in chrome (also incognito), in safari works normally

server log for delete

```
Started DELETE "/disc/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-19 11:47:59 +0300
Processing by DiscController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {PARAMS}
 // REVELVANT SQL WORKING
   (3.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered discs/destroy.js.erb (3.3ms)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 18.7ms | ActiveRecord: 18.1ms)
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#disc-<%= @disc.id %>").hide('slow');
```

the destroy action

```
def destroy
  @disc = Disc.find params[:id]
  @disc.destroy
end
```

Comment: Since everything seems to be rendering and working according to your server logs so i think there's something wrong with your js code in destroy.js.erb. Can you post your server logs and js code

Comment: related html do get hide or not ?

Comment: Do you see any error in browsers console? You sure there exists an element with the id used in js.erb template?

Comment: No errors, the problems is that the next UJS request (like a create via post) fires on the server, the js response doesn't get rendered. If I don't send a delete request before, it works fine

Comment: show `delete` action.

Comment: @NickGinanto Your destroy action looks fine to me, `the next UJS request (like a create via post) fires on the server, the js response doesn't get rendered` so don't you think the problem is with create and not destroy?

Comment: But that's not the case, since consecutive `create`s work fine, until a `delete`

Comment: @NickGinanto can you reproduce your issue and post logs in that case? Also can you add your create action and create.js.erb

Comment: Reproduction is easy, I might as well build a sample app to simulate this

Comment: The problem will either be with your JS in the `destroy.js.erb`, or with how you're receiving the response. Can you put an alert in `destroy.js.erb` to test to see if it will work?

Comment: the destroy js works fine. The problem is that the response on the ajax requests after it don't get rendered

Answer (score 0):

After destroy you won't find `@disc.id` on view ie. `destroy.js.erb`. That's why you won't see any reflection on view side. save deleted element id in any instance variable in controller and then try add hide things using that variable value instead of deleted object id.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling `turbolinks` in rails 4.

**If we create a new Rails 4 application and decide not to use Turbolinks we can easily remove it by commenting-out the gem in the gemfile and the require statement in the application’s JavaScript manifest file.**